# Java: Alternative to handling a strange error/return type with exceptions

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I have a function as part of a rectangle class (points inside it are immutable doubles, so the rectangle is also immutable), and I need to provide a method for calculating intersections with another rectangle. The method will return the calculated intersection rectangle. However, if the objects do not intersect at all, it throws an exception.

The only alternative to throwing an exception I could think of would be to return a special type called RectIntersection, and the caller could poll that object to see if the intersection calculation failed or not. I like this better than throwing an exception, but it leaves me needing to test every call to this function to check the newly created object.

Any other suggestions for handling this condition?

```
static public DoubleRect calcRectIntersection(DoubleRect r1, DoubleRect r2) throws DoubleRectException {

    if((r1.topLeft.x > r2.bottomRight.x || r1.bottomRight.x < r2.topLeft.x || r1.topLeft.y > r2.bottomRight.y || r1.bottomRight.y < r2.topLeft.y) != true)
    {
        return new DoubleRect(r1.topLeft.x >= r2.topLeft.x ? r1.topLeft.x : r2.topLeft.x,
                r1.topLeft.y >= r2.topLeft.y ? r1.topLeft.y : r2.topLeft.y,
                r1.bottomRight.x <= r2.bottomRight.x ? r1.bottomRight.x : r2.bottomRight.x,
                r1.bottomRight.y <= r2.bottomRight.y ? r1.bottomRight.y : r2.bottomRight.y);
    }
    else throw new DoubleRectException("Call to calcRectIntersection() could not complete since the two rectangles did not intersect");
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using an exception for normal control flow.  Two non-intersecting rectangles sounds like normal control flow to me.  Why not return a zero-size rectangle?

Comment: For reference, `if ((humongously long condition) != true)` royally sucks for readability. Recommend `if (!(humoungously long condition))`, or even better, `if (logical inversion of humongously long condition)` instead.

Comment: What @cHao said: also `if (condition != true)` is the same as `if (!condition)`.

Comment: I'm porting this from C. The original was !condition. Java doesn't seem to like the original syntax.

Comment: And consider using a `max` function for that mass of ternaries.

Comment: I assume you are restricting yourself to rectangles parallel/perpendicular to the origin.  Without this restriction, the intersection of 2 rectangles need not be another rectange.  For example it could be a triangle.

Comment: Yeah, they are all parallel to each other (straight vertical/horizontal edges). I've gotten a lot of comments about refactoring to make code more readable, but refactoring all of those little calculations would add a lot of the JVM setting up temporary stack frames for a lot of stuff that can just be done inline like shown. It's faster. If Java offered inlining methods it would be cool, but they don't. I know that JVM can auto-inline what it thinks it needs to, but I don't like depending on it. I just put it like it is. For my eyes only so garbling is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just return `null`? You just check to make sure the return value isn't null before using it.

Or, as Oli noted, return an empty rectangle. Arguably, that's what the intersection of two nonoverlapping rectangles is anyway. You may not even need to modify the code that uses it (it's easy to forsee code that does nothing given an empty rect), or you can add an isEmpty method to check the result. There's precdent for this, in the [Rectangle class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersection%28java.awt.Rectangle%29%20Rectangle%20class)

You're right, exceptions aren't really the tool to use for nonexceptional conditions.

Comment: +1 - Make sure you add the appropriate comments to your method indicating that a return value of null indicates that the rectangles don't intersect. That way, it should be plain to all who use this method.

Comment: You're right. Arguably that's what the intersection of two non-overlapping rects *is*.

Comment: True, but that's what I was trying to avoid, so I could use object.method().method().method() if necessary. The exception throwing makes it safe, but I guess I'll need to figure out another way.

Comment: First of all, that's not fantastic coding style. You'll frequently find that you need to do something with the intermediate values, but you've lost them - so you need to go back and change it anyway

Second of all, not necessarily. Your other methods may work just fine with an empty rectangle, depending.

Comment: You should see the code for the DoublePoint for calculating angles. Refactoring little calculations to their own methods would make it a pinch more readable, but it would make the method nearly twice as slow. I don't really mind the garbling, since these classes are not for public domain; just for my apps.